# Types don't match for creating a CLR Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, sqlclr

I have a method in an assembly that looks like this:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
  public class MyClass
  {
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void MyMethod(SqlChars myMessage)
    {
       // Stuff here 
    } 
  }
}
```

I compile that to a dll and load it into my SQL Server like this:

```
drop assembly MyAssembly
create assembly MyAssemblyfrom 'C:\Scripts\MyAssembly.dll'
```

That all works fine.

But now I try to run this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MySproc @message nvarchar(max)
AS EXTERNAL NAME MyAssembly.[MyNameSpace.MyClass].MyMethod
```

When I run that I get this Error:

> CREATE PROCEDURE for "MySproc " failed because T-SQL and CLR types for parameter "@myMessage" do not match.

**Any ideas how I can resolve this?**

I have also Tried these method signatures:

- `public static void MyMethod(string myMessage)`
- `public static void MyMethod([SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)] string myMessage)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sql type `nvarchar` maps to CLR (.Net) type  `SqlString`:

```
public static void MyMethod(SqlString myMessage)
{
    if (! myMessage.IsNull) 
    {
        String myMessageString = myMessage.ToString();
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is a link showingg the mapping of CLR to SQL Server Data Types

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx

In your case SQLChars maps to nvarchar