# SQL CLR issue: CREATE PROCEDURE failed because parameter counts do not match

Tags: c#, sql-server, file, t-sql, sqlclr

I did check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899197/types-dont-match-for-creating-a-clr-stored-procedure) but the problem doesn't appears to be with mismatch of type.

I'm trying to use CLR to convert back a file from blob data.  Below is the c# code converted to dll and stored using assembly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;


namespace CLRProcedures
{
   public class WriteFile
    {
        [SqlFunction]
        public static SqlInt32 WriteToFile(SqlBytes binary, SqlString path, SqlBoolean append)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!binary.IsNull && !path.IsNull && !append.IsNull)
                {
                    var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path.Value);
                    if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
                    using (var fs = new FileStream(path.Value, append ? FileMode.Append : FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                    {
                        byte[] byteArr = binary.Value;
                        for (int i = 0; i < byteArr.Length; i++)
                        {
                            fs.WriteByte(byteArr[i]);
                        };
                    }
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                   return 0;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return -2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SQL queries are as below :

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY FileOutput from 'c:\dlls\CLRProcedures.dll' WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE 

CREATE PROCEDURE FileOutput
@file varbinary(max),
@filepath nvarchar(4000),
@append bit,
@message int OUTPUT    
AS    
EXTERNAL NAME FileOutput.[CLRProcedures.WriteFile].WriteToFile
```

This throws error : 'CREATE PROCEDURE failed because parameter counts do not match.'

I've re-verified from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-types-net-framework/mapping-clr-parameter-data?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) if there is type mismatch but there isnt one. Where could I be going wrong ? I tried to change the return type of c# code but same issue.

Thank you

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `@message int OUTPUT` parameter?

Comment: `output` is not the same as return value; `output` is kinda like `ref` in .NET

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/dev-guide/clr-stored-procedures?view=sql-server-2014 shows how to use an OUTPUT parameter if you really want to do it that way.

Comment: What datatype should a parameter named "message" be? Doesn't sound like numeric to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ignoring what the error message is saying:

> CREATE PROCEDURE failed because parameter ***counts*** do not match  (emphasis added)

The parameter "count", not any particular parameter "type", is the issue. You have 3 input parameters in the method signature but are specifying 4 parameters in the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.

Your options are:

1. Do as Naji is suggesting and add a 4th parameter, declared as `out` in the C# code, and change the `return` to setting that `message` variable, which would match the 4 parameters you have defined.
2. Or, you can keep the C# code as-is and get that return value the same way that you would a regular T-SQL stored proc return value:

   ```sql
   DECLARE @ReturnValue INT;

   EXEC @ReturnValue = dbo.FileOutput 0x1234, N'path', 1;

   SELECT @ReturnValue;
   ```
3. Or, you can even switch to having this be a function by simply changing the T-SQL `CREATE` object statement to be:

   ```sql
   CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FileOutput
   (
     @File VARBINARY(MAX),
     @FilePath NVARCHAR(4000),
     @Append BIT
   )
   RETURNS INT
   AS EXTERNAL NAME ...
   ```

   And use as follows:

   ```sql
   DECLARE @ReturnValue INT;

   SET @ReturnValue = dbo.FileOutput(0x1234, N'path', 1);

   SELECT @ReturnValue;
   ```

   (Technically, as a scalar function that returns an `INT` / `Int32`, you can even execute it using the same stored procedure syntax as shown in option 2 above)

**ALSO:**

1. If you are creating a procedure, you should decorate the C# `WriteToFile` method with `SqlProcedure` instead of `SqlFunction`.
2. Rather than iterating over the entire binary value as a `byte[]`, the `SqlBytes` type offers a `Stream` property that is an actual stream that is a more efficient way of reading that value. Just copy `binary.Stream` to the file stream and be done :-)
3. Always specify a schema name (for schema-bound objects), whether in `CREATE` statements, `SELECT`, `EXEC`, etc.

For more info on working with SQLCLR in general, please visit: [SQLCLR Info](https://sqlclr.org/)

Comment: thank you fo explaining what was actually going on. i've still not been able to export file due to Path.GetDirectoryName throws error 'Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed'.   Google search suggests to set permission mode to UNSAFE while creating assembly. When I try to do so that throws error that 'Assembly 'CLRProcedures' cannot be loaded because this edition of SQL Server only supports SAFE assemblies.'   which means its linux hosted sql server ??

Comment: previously I was trying to create the file back from blob data via 'OLE automation procedures' but enabling it is not possible as it not being suggested by higher authorities.[even when i tried to enable, it said it cannot be done on this version of sql server].   
Now i'm told to try via bcp but have no idea how to approach

Comment: @ShaliniRaj Please update the main question with that additional info: a) what you are actually trying to accomplish (the end goal, not just this intermediate step of exporting a file), and b) what version/platform of SQL Server you are using. Thanks. That will help readers in general get a better understanding of what is going on, but it sounds like the actual question has been resolved/answered and you are now moving onto another question.

Comment: @ShaliniRaj I can say that if you are running on Linux then that won't be able to do file system stuff. Either way, `UNSAFE` is bad advice as it's unnecessary. `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` would handle that. Please see: [Stairway to SQLCLR Level 4: Security (EXTERNAL and UNSAFE Assemblies)](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/stairway-to-sqlclr-level-4-security-external-and-unsafe-assemblies) and [SQLCLR vs. SQL Server 2017, Part 2: “CLR strict security” – Solution 1](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/08/09/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-2-clr-strict-security-solution-1/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the OUTPUT parameter to the `WriteToFile` function to return value

```
[SqlFunction]
public static void WriteToFile(SqlBytes binary, SqlString path, SqlBoolean append,out SqlInt32 message)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!binary.IsNull && !path.IsNull && !append.IsNull)
            {
                var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path.Value);
                if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
                using (var fs = new FileStream(path.Value, append ? FileMode.Append : FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    byte[] byteArr = binary.Value;
                    for (int i = 0; i < byteArr.Length; i++)
                    {
                        fs.WriteByte(byteArr[i]);
                    };
                }
                message = 1;
            }
            else
                message = 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            message = -2;
        }
    }
```

for more details : [CLR Stored Procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/dev-guide/clr-stored-procedures?view=sql-server-2014)

Comment: I suspect this is going in the wrong direction - and the real "fix" is to remove the parameter from the SP declaration (using the return value instead)

Comment: @MarcGravell why ? he can add the missing out parameter to the method and return the message value

Comment: @NajiMakhoul He could, but that parameter is being used to indicate the success/failure state, which is an idiomatic use of the return value of a stored procedure

Comment: thank you fo explaining what was actually going on. i've still not been able to export file due to Path.GetDirectoryName throws error 'Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed'. Google search suggests to set permission mode to UNSAFE while creating assembly. When I try to do so that throws error that 'Assembly 'CLRProcedures' cannot be loaded because this edition of SQL Server only supports SAFE assemblies.' which means its linux hosted sql server ??

Comment: previously I was trying to create the file back from blob data via 'OLE automation procedures' but enabling it is not possible as it not being suggested by higher authorities.[even when i tried to enable, it said it cannot be done on this version of sql server]. Now i'm told to try via bcp but have no idea how to approach –

Comment: @ShaliniRaj check this : https://en.dirceuresende.com/blog/clr-resolving-system-security-permissions-fileiopermission-problem-on-sql-server/

Comment: @ShaliniRaj and NajiMakhoul: please do _not_ follow the advice shown in that dirceuresende. com link posted by Naji. Using `UNSAFE` / Unrestricted for simple file system access is unnecessary and is bad advice. You only need `EXTERNAL_ACCESS`, though you won't be able to use that or `UNSAFE` on Linux.